# Getting the gazebo plugin p3d working (hydro)

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Ros Hydro;
Gazebo 1.9.2;

Hello guys,

The last 2 days I am trying to figure out how to get this little plugin to work:

```
<gazebo>
<plugin name="my_box_controller" plugin="libros_p3d.so">
  <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
  <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
  <bodyName>base_link</bodyName>
  <topicName>mObstacle_GT</topicName>
  <gaussianNoise>0.0</gaussianNoise>
  <frameName>base_link</frameName>
  <!--interface:position name="my_box_p3d_position_iface" /-->
</plugin>
```

and this is the error that I get

Error [parser.cc:492] Required attribute[filename] in element[plugin] is not specified in SDF.

I bet I got confused with the whole URDF, XACRO, SDF stuff. I could post the rest of my code, even though it is just a box. Also, it might be worth mentioning that everything works fin when I remove the plugin.

Of course I looked at the tutorial but it was not very helpful (or did I miss something?):
http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Motor_and_Sensor_Plugins#P3D_.283D_Position_Interface_for_Ground_Truth.29

Thanks in advance guys,
Marcus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5308/getting-the-gazebo-plugin-p3d-working-(hydro)/) by [Marcus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/541/marcus/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-01-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Here is an example:

```
<gazebo>
  <plugin name="ground_truth" filename="libgazebo_ros_p3d.so">
    <frameName>map</frameName>
    <bodyName>base_link</bodyName>
    <topicName>odom</topicName>
    <updateRate>30.0</updateRate>
  </plugin>
</gazebo>
```

---

Originally posted by [Jim Rothrock](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/408/jim-rothrock/) with karma: 247 on 2014-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marcus](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/541/marcus/) on 2014-01-28**:
This works perfectly. Thank you Jim.

**Comment by [zhenshan](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6661/zhenshan/) on 2018-09-16**:
that also works for me

**Comment by [PGHowzLife](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/21949/pghowzlife/) on 2019-12-31**:
Whenever I try using it, unfortunately, I don't any published message from Gazebo of the /odom topic. Is there any posibility of extracting the position and orientation (Odometry) from Gazebo with this plugin?